# no valid constructor on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

This is my code:

```
class FNNode(val name: String)

case class Ingredient(override val name: String, category: String) extends FNNode(name)


val ingredients: RDD[(VertexId, FNNode)] = 
sc.textFile(PATH+"ingr_info.tsv").
      filter(! _.startsWith("#")).
      map(line => line.split('\t')).
      map(x => (x(0).toInt ,Ingredient(x(1), x(2))))
```

and there are no errors when I define these variables. However, when trying to execute it:

```
ingredients.take(1)
```

I get

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Exception while getting task result: java.io.InvalidClassException: $iwC$$iwC$Ingredient; no valid constructor
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
```

It seems this could be related to Serialization issues as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210952/scala-invalidclassexception-no-valid-constructor) . However, I have no idea of how to solve this if it is indeed a Serialization issue.

I'm following along the code in [this](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/apache-spark-graph-processing) book by they way, so I would assume this should have at least worked at some point?

Comment: FNNode has to be a case class as well unless I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this: "error: case class Ingredient has case ancestor $iwC.$iwC.FNNode, but case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes"

Comment: Can you try, whether it helps to let FNNode extend Serializable?

Comment: This code actually works fine for me (in local mode) :/

Comment: what spark/scala version are you using?

Comment: @TzachZohar These serialization errors do never occur in local mode (Unfortunatelly...), as the classes are not needed to send over the network and hence are not serialized at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This fixed your issue for me:

```
class FNNode(val name: String) extends Serializable
```